# csv file upload and update mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am very to new to php. i am using the following code to open a csv file and update my database. i need to check the value of first row-first column of the csv file. if it is matching "some text 1", then i need to run code1, if it is "some text 2", run code2, else code3. I can use if else condition but since i am using while loop It fails. Can anyone help me.

```
    $handle = fopen($file_tmp,"r");
        while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,",")) !== false) 
        {
                    // I need to check here
        $companycode =  mysql_real_escape_string($fileop[0]);
        $Item = mysql_real_escape_string($fileop[3]);
        $pack = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\. -]/', '', $fileop[4]);
        $lastmonth = mysql_real_escape_string($fileop[5]);
        $ltlmonth = mysql_real_escape_string($fileop[6]);
        $op = mysql_real_escape_string($fileop[9]);
        $pur = mysql_real_escape_string($fileop[10]);
        $sale = mysql_real_escape_string($fileop[12]);
        $bal = mysql_real_escape_string($fileop[17]);
        $bval = mysql_real_escape_string($fileop[18]);
        $sval = mysql_real_escape_string($fileop[19]);

        $sq1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `sas` (companycode,Item,pack,lastmonth,ltlmonth,op,pur,sale,bal,bval,sval) VALUES ('$companycode','$Item','$pack','$lastmonth','$ltlmonth','$op','$pur','$sale','$bal','$bval','$sval')");
    }
```

Comment: Stop using the long depreciated mysql extension. Use prepared statements instead, then you do not need all those escaping commands and your code gets safe.

Comment: What do you mean by "since i am using while loop It fails"? I cannot spot any conditional (`if`) here...

Comment: okay I am learning PDO too. Is there a way to do what i asked

Comment: @arkascha i have not mentioned if

Comment: Citation from your question: "I can use if else condition"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a switch statement?

Case 1: you have to fire a different action for every row:

```
$handle = fopen($file_tmp,'r');
while(FALSE!==($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,','))) {
    switch($fileop[0]) {
        case 'some text 1':
            // do thing 1
            $sql = '...';
            break;
        case 'some text 2':
            // do thing 2
            $sql = '...';
            break;
        case 'some text 3':
            // do thing 3
            $sql = '...';
            break;
        default:
            $sql = FALSE;
    } // switch
} // while

if (FALSE!==$sql) {
    // now go on with the $sql statement and execute it using `mysqli` or `PDO`...
} // if
```

Explanation: you check the first column for each row you read (`$fileop[0]`) and decide which action to fire.

---

Case 2: you have to fire a different action for each file:

```
$handle = fopen($file_tmp,'r');
$action = NULL;
while(FALSE!==($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,','))) {
    if (is_null($action)) {
        switch($fileop[0]) {
            case 'some text 1': $action = 1; break;
            case 'some text 2': $action = 2; break;
            case 'some text 3': $action = 3; break;
            default:            $action = FALSE;
        } // switch
    } // if
    switch ($action) {
        case 1:
            $sql = '...';
            // prepare statement, use $fileop as array of attributes for the statement
            break;
        case 2:
            $sql = '...';
            // prepare statement, use $fileop as array of attributes for the statement
            break;
        case 2:
            $sql = '...';
            // prepare statement, use $fileop as array of attributes for the statement
            break;
    } // switch
} // while
```

Explanation: you check the first column in the first row you read (`$fileop[0]`). You only do this when `$action` is still `NULL`. Once `$action` has been set you leave it. Now you have `$action` defined once at the beginning of your processing step and can react on it for every single row you read.

---

In general it might pay out to use exceptions in this to handle an unexpected first column value, so that you can skip reading the whole file in such case...

Comment: your code didnt help. Let me explain once again. i have two differnt csv files. File1 contains text1 in the first cell. File2 has text2. when a csv file is uploaded it has to check the first row first column value, if the value is text1 and the file uploaded is File1 so it should run while loop code to insert data into database. The code you suggested is checking each and every row $fileop[0]

Comment: That is indeed how I understood your question. I added a second case which hopefully guides you into the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

why not to load directly to mysql?

```
load data local infile 'filename.csv' into table tblname
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(field1, field1, field1,...);
```

Comment: upload csv to server and then load it to mysql?